# How to use Proxy when using ICE to write a multi-thread client app?

Tags: java, client, ice

How will ICE do when one proxy is shared by multi-thread? Will the requests be queued on the same connection which is behind the proxy? Though a proxy can bind to different connections, at a time a proxy can only use one connection.

For example, I have get a proxy named proxyA using stringToProxy method. In order to access remote service, I create two threads using the proxy as construct parameter and use the same proxy in both threads. Is this the right way to do so? or I need create two proxies? or create proxy every time before I need to use proxy?

From my knowledge, I choose the way to create proxy every time when needed because proxy is light weighted and the established connections will be cached by ICE run time and reused by later created proxy. Here all proxies are to connect to the same server and port.